# What is the best material to make snow on miniatures?

Tags: material-selection, miniatures

What is the best material to make snow on miniatures except crushed glass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like many things to do with miniatures, there are things you can buy and things you can make.

#### Buy

You can buy what's known as [modelling snow](https://www.noch.com/en/product-categories/model-landscaping/snow-winter.html) from most manufacturers of scenic products. This is likely to contain crushed glass, but does save you from crushing it yourself.

#### Make

The other well known material for making snow is Bicarbonate of Soda (AKA *Baking Soda*) - available at virtually every food shop or supermarket. This looks great at first, but over a period of a few years becomes increasingly yellow.

I've also heard of people using flour...don't do this. It's too coarse, and has a tendency to *rot* if you're not careful.

[image: Bicarbonate of Soda snow]
      *Image from a [basing tutorial](http://coloursandeagles.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/basing-tutorial-snow-tarmac-urban-winter.html) I wrote a few years ago showing snow made with bicarbonate of soda.*

I also recommend that you use water effects (clear resin) to stick the snow down instead of PVA, it looks better.